# Distribution of the difference of two independent uniform variables, truncated at 0

Tags: self-study, random-variable

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random variables having the same uniform distribution $U(0,1)$ with density

$f(x)=1$ if $0≤x≤1$ (and $0$ elsewhere).

Let $Z$ be a real random variable defined by:

$Z=X-Y$ if $X>Y$ (and $0$ elsewhere).

1. Derive the distribution of $Z$.
2. Compute the expectation $E(Z)$ and variance $V(Z)$.

Comment: Homework? What have you tried and where are you stuck? Do you know how to find the distribution of a *sum* of independent random variables. If you do then, **hint**: $X - Y = X + (-Y)$. That said, your question doesn't seem to be asking about the distribution of a (pure) subtraction. So, providing some details on your thought process will help users here guide you in the right direction.

Comment: i am preparing for an exam after leaving university for 5 years and working in a totally different field that has nothing to do even with numbers.

Comment: my problem here starts with the logic of the problem. i know it has to do with probability density function, but adding or subtracting the functions is getting me nowhere. another thing is the difference between the part 1 and 2 as i know that the distribution of the varibale is knowing its mean and variance and part 2 is asking the same question. i hope someone can help me with this as i dont have much time in preparation and it is the first time i get to such kind of problems while preparing. thanks to all in advance

Comment: I suggest you start with a simpler example of discrete random variables. That will hopefully help you see what is going on. Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are uniform on $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. Then what is the distribution of $X + Y$? And, $X - Y$? (Note also that the mean and variance *do not* fully characterize a distribution, so the two parts of the question are *not* the same.)

Comment: The distribution is more than just the mean and variance, so you should review the distinction among the three.  Then consider relying on first principles.  E.g., drawing a picture of the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ in the $x,y$-plane along with level curves of $Z=X-Y$ will provide an immediate (and easy) geometric derivation of the distribution of $Z$.

Comment: Is this exactly how the problem is originally stated?  Or does the problem ask for the *conditional* distribution of $Z$ given that $X\gt Y$?

Comment: Hint:  Since $P\{X < Y\} = \frac{1}{2}$ (think about why this must be so), $Z$ has value $0$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$. Thus, $Z$ is what is sometimes called a _mixed_ random variable which takes on some values with nonzero probability and behaves as a continuous random variable for some values. As @whuber does, I too ask whether you have mis-stated the problem.  It leads to more complications than one would expect from a typical end-of-chapter problem at the apparent level of the book you are using.

Answer (score 5):

Check p. 18 of [Probability Distributions as Program Variables](http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/publications/thesis/online/IM090722.pdf),  by Dimitrios Milios.

He has discussed the problem in an fairly detailed manner.