# Convolution: PDF of difference of uniform random variables

Tags: distributions, density-function, uniform-distribution, convolution

PDF of $X$: [image]

PDF of $Y$: [image]

$Z=X-Y$, $T=X+2Y$, how to find the PDF of $Z$ and $T$ and plot them?

Comment: Are $X, Y$ independent? Does [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution) help?

Comment: This https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18152/distribution-of-the-difference-of-two-independent-uniform-variables-truncated-a  in not (yet) a duplicate because it does have only a link-answer

Comment: You could apply any of the five methods I describe at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/43075/919.  But are you asking how to find the *joint* pdf of $(Z,T)$ or to find their *marginal* pdfs separately?